# Is it risky to sign APK for my customer?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, developer-console, android-app-signing

I am Android developer, I have some Android apps in Google Play. I am developing apps for my customers.

Is there any risk to sign APK of my customer apps on my PC?

Suppose that, I signed APK and published on Google Play with my customer's account. Then, one day my customer app or account is banned.

I think, Google tracks MAC address, IP address, etc. when an app is published on Google Play.

Then, is there any risk for my developer account, apps if my customer's account is banned from Google Play? Because my apps and my customer's app is signed by same PC. Google track it, may Google punish me also?

Comment: _I think, Google tracks MAC address, IP address..._ I don't think so... both values may change...eespecially the ip

Comment: I think the only thing that matters is the keystore that you use to sign the APK, nothing else !

Comment: Never heard a case of this, just make sure you create a new signing keystore just for the customer and don't use that for your own apps.  If they want to take the app and maintain it themselves you'll have to share the keystore and you probably don't want to share one for your own apps.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely use a different key for each customer. Then if the customer decides to get a different developer to develop their app for them you can hand them the key, and it doesn't compromise any other apps. It is just good business.

But why not just use [Google Play App Signing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423)? That way you don't have to worry about who signs it. Google will do it for you. And they will help you with any transfer process in future, or if you lose your signing keys, for example if your hard drive fails.

Also, I would definitely stay away from customers you think are doing stuff that might get their accounts banned. You don't want to be associated with them and risk your other customers.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the Google Play App Signing. It's a feature that had completely passed me by!